# How to get only one from multiple columns MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got database which contains products assigned to users. But if user_id is 0 then product is assigned to everyone and if it contains specyfic ID then it's connected with specyfic user.
Now I want to get all product for the user and if user has not product assigned, then i want to get product assigned to everyone.

Here is how my table looks like:

```
ID | PRODUCT ID | ACTIVE | CUSTOMER ID
1  | 100        | 1      | 0 
2  | 100        | 0      | 24
3  | 101        | 1      | 0 
4  | 101        | 0      | 24
5  | 103        | 1      | 0
```

And now i want to get just rows with ID 2, 4, 5. I tried to do this by:

```
SELECT `id`, `product_id`, MAX(`customer_id`), `active`
FROM `products`
WHERE `customer_id` IN (0,24)
GROUP BY `product_id`
ORDER BY `product_id`
LIMIT 50
```

But result was not that what i expected to be..

I've got MySQL 5.6

Comment: I'm confused your question talks about user but there is no user in the table,

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: I fail to see how only wanting rows 2, 4 and 5 corresponds to what you said earlier. Could you elaborate why only those should be returned?

Comment: @P.Salmon I forgot, customer_id = user_id, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want a prioritization:

```
select *
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id order by customer_id desc) as seqnum
      from products p
      where p.customer_id in (0, 24)
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one row per product where `0` or `24` is assigned.  The row gives preference to customer 24 over 0.

An alternative method is to use `union all` (assuming the above logic is what you want):

```
select p.*
from products p
where p.customer_id = 24 or
      (p.customer_id = 0 and
       not exists (select 1
                   from products p2
                   where p2.product_id = p.product_id and
                         p2.customer_id = 24
                  )
      );
```

Comment: There is not ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL 5.6

Comment: @Akhmed . . . That information was added after I answered.

Comment: @GordonLinoff your 2nd query is already given as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE p.customer_id = 24
   OR (
     p.customer_id = 0
     AND 
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE product_id = p.product_id AND customer_id = 24)
   )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1c338625b80602101585f768c37f9e4e).
Results:

```
> id | product_id | active | customer_id
> -: | ---------: | -----: | ----------:
>  2 |        100 |      0 |          24
>  4 |        101 |      0 |          24
>  5 |        103 |      1 |           0
```